# Python 2.7: Appending to a list value of a dictionary key

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have the following data:

```
data = [(1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (2, 1), (2, 2), (2, 3)]
```

and I want to create a dictionary which contains key-list value, how can I do this with a dictionary comprehension?

i.e.:

```
{1: [2,3,4]
 2: [1,2,3]
}
```

I have tried the following but the list gets overwritten on every iteration.

```
{x: [y] for x,y in data}
```

Comment: @Bhargav Rao what do you mean by that?

Comment: Do you want a solution using a dictionary comprehension only?

Comment: yes that would be nice if possible or a combination of a list comprehension with a default dict seems good too

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use this dict-comprehension:

```
d = {x: [v for u,v in data if u == x] for x,y in data}
```

Note, however, that this is pretty inefficient, as it will loop the entire list `n+1` times!

Better use just a plain-old `for` loop:

```
d = {}
for x,y in data:
    d.setdefault(x, []).append(y)
```

Alternatively, you could also use [`itertools.groupy`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) (as discovered by yourself):

```
groups = itertools.groupby(sorted(data), key=lambda x: x[0])
d = {k: [g[1] for g in group] for k, group in groups}
```

In all cases, `d` ends up being `{1: [2, 3, 4], 2: [1, 2, 3]}`

Comment: I think your answer is pretty close and has given me a hint on how to do it, could you update your answer to include groupby in itertools?
from itertools import groupby
data = [(1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (2, 1), (2, 2), (2, 3)]
{key: [value[1] for value in groupValues] for key, groupValues in groupby(data, lambda x: x[0])}

Comment: @Har Nice idea, using `groupby`. Added this to my answer. You could, however, also post your own answer to your question...

Comment: Thanks @tobias_ it doesn't seem fair though as you guys have both put in the effort of replying to a question which I have asked.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html) from collections module.

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> data = [(1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (2, 1), (2, 2), (2, 3)]
>>> m = defaultdict(list)
>>> for i,j in data:
        m[i].append(j)


>>> m
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {1: [2, 3, 4], 2: [1, 2, 3]})
>>> dict(m)
{1: [2, 3, 4], 2: [1, 2, 3]}
```