# dictionary created using zip with combining two list

Tags: python, python-2.7

When i use the zip function to create a dictionary from two lists like below , not all key value pairs are stored in the dictionary

```
>>> selfips=['1.0.0.1', '165.1.4.5', '165.3.4.5', '165.3.4.4', '165.3.4.4']
>>> statefloatingselfips=['STATE_DISABLED', 'STATE_DISABLED', 'STATE_DISABLED', 'STATE_ENABLED', 'STATE_ENABLED']
>>> floatdict=dict(zip(statefloatingselfips, selfips))
>>> print floatdict
{'STATE_ENABLED': '165.3.4.4', 'STATE_DISABLED': '165.3.4.5'}
```

Comment: Do you want to map states to lists of IPs, or IPs to states? In the first case, just reverse the arguments to `zip`, in the latter case, see [this related question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28718700/1639625).

Comment: No, they are being mapped. You're simply overwriting keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have dictionary - state: list of adresses

```
map_by_state = collections.defaultdict(list)

for state, address in zip (statefloatingselfips, selfips):
    map_by_state[state].append(address)
```

Answer (score 3):

As the keys of a dictionary are unique, you can use [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) for such tasks :

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> d=defaultdict(list)
>>> for i,j in zip(statefloatingselfips, selfips):
...     d[i].append(j)
... 
>>> d
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'STATE_ENABLED': ['165.3.4.4', '165.3.4.4'], 'STATE_DISABLED': ['1.0.0.1', '165.1.4.5', '165.3.4.5']})
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't have multiple keys with similar value. Instead, you can use a [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) to make a `set` of all ips that share a status:

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(set)
selfips=['1.0.0.1', '165.1.4.5', '165.3.4.5', '165.3.4.4', '165.3.4.4']
statefloatingselfips=[
    'STATE_DISABLED', 'STATE_DISABLED', 'STATE_DISABLED',
    'STATE_ENABLED', 'STATE_ENABLED'
]

for ip, state in zip(selfips, statefloatingselfips):
    d[state].add(ip)

print d
```

Output:

```
defaultdict(<type 'set'>, {
    'STATE_ENABLED': set(['165.3.4.4']),
    'STATE_DISABLED': set(['1.0.0.1', '165.3.4.5', '165.1.4.5'])
})
```